# Black screen when present new controller and dismiss current controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Currently I have 3 controllers, A, B and C. I click one button in `AController` and  present `BController`, then I call one api in `BController`, if it is successful, I wanner go to `CController`, but I want to dismiss `BController` at the same time. Then I call another api in `CController` successfully, when I dismiss `CController`, I hope the screen will go back to `Acontroller`. All the three controllers are not in navigation controller stack.

My implementation:

In `BController`, call `presentViewController:(CController)` method and `dismissViewController:(self)`, but I failed, the screen is nothing with black color, hope some guys can help me solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't call dismissViewController:self, because BController is PRESENTING viewController for CController, and dismissing doesn't make sence

Comment: But I don't need BController anymore. I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: present view C in callback viewDidDisappear of B controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do the following:

```
1) A -> present B

2) B executes some method and if it is success -> delegate method to A, 
f.e (void)bControllerDidSuccess


3) in A Controller delegate method (void)bControllerDidSuccess: 
    A dismissViewController; // A dissmising B
    A presentViewController:C // A presenting C
```

Comment: It is a way, of course, especially if more than 3 controllers. In this particular case it is simpler to dismiss presentingViewController as described below.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your normal way and add this line when you want to dismiss the CController

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: There is no navigation controller for application.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- from A present B with presentViewController:animated:completion:
- from B present C with presentViewController:animated:completion:
- when conditions are met on C, just dismiss property "presentingVIewController" on C with dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, effectively dismissing B controller that will dismiss C automatically and you "land" on A controller